# Oracle SQL Subqueries

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to select the person who has worked less than the  average total hours that anyone has worked and a camp

Tables are Person and Schedule

this is what I have so far:

```
 SELECT fname AS "First Name", lname AS "Last Name", 
 SUM((end_time - start_time) * 24)         
 FROM person JOIN schedule USING (person_ID)
 GROUP BY fname
 HAVING SUM((end_time - start_time) * 24) < (
 SELECT AVG(SUM((end_time - start_time) * 24)) FROM schedule);`
```

Person has fname, lname, and person_ID
Schedule has sched_id, s_date, start_time, end_time, and person_id

Thank you!

Getting this error:

```
Error starting at line 18 in command:
    SELECT fname AS "First Name", lname AS "Last Name", 
    SUM((end_time - start_time) * 24)     
    FROM person JOIN schedule USING (person_ID)
    GROUP BY fname
    HAVING SUM((end_time - start_time) * 24) < (
    SELECT AVG(SUM((end_time - start_time) * 24)) FROM schedule)
    Error at Command Line:18 Column:31
    Error report:
    SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
    00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
   *Cause:    
   *Action:
```

Comment: You have to include all the non-aggregate columns from the select into the group by clause.

Answer (score 1):

The GROUP BY line needs to include all of the non-aggregated fields in your SELECT statement (so everything except for SUM() in this case).

Try changing it to:

```
GROUP BY fname, lname
```

Answer (score 0):

When using an aggregate function such as SUM, you will need to include all your non-aggregate properties in the group by:

```
 SELECT fname AS "First Name", lname AS "Last Name", 
 SUM((end_time - start_time) * 24)         
 FROM person JOIN schedule USING (person_ID)
 GROUP BY fname, lname --this is changed
 HAVING SUM((end_time - start_time) * 24) < (
 SELECT AVG(SUM((end_time - start_time) * 24)) FROM schedule);`
```

Comment: now it is saying
Error at Command Line:27 Column:16
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00978: nested group function without GROUP BY
00978. 00000 -  "nested group function without GROUP BY"

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this problem is with analytic functions:

```
select "First Name", "Last Name", hours
from (SELECT fname AS "First Name", lname AS "Last Name",
             SUM((end_time - start_time) * 24) as hours,
             avg(SUM((end_time - start_time) * 24)) over () as avghours
      FROM person JOIN
           schedule
           USING (person_ID)
      GROUP BY fname, lname
     ) t
WHERE hours < avghours;
```

The specific problem reported by Oracle is that `avg(sum())` is not allowed for a `group by` (unless, as above, the `avg()` is really an analytic function).